# switch between terminal and folder in ubntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I have 7 terminals open at a time and if i open any folder or browser and i press alt + tab, only the recent terminal shows up. Is there a shortcut so that it opens shows all the terminals? I am using ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks

Comment: Works fine as is here. When using the alt+tab switcher & switching (arrow key) to any app with multiple windows open it goes to a spread showing all of those multiple windows (- which can then be parsed thru with the arrow key). Does that not happen for you?

Comment: Using workspaces is one solution for it. Please write if you know some other simple solution.

Comment: It works but i want to look at changes in all the terminals at once and that was lil inconvinient using arrows.

Comment: Then just go to a spread directly, bindings shown when pressing & holding super button > Windows section or just d. click terminal launcher icon

Comment: Unity worked like you would want in its very first versions. Nowadays, gnome shell (and thus stock Ubuntu since version 17.10) still works this way. Using workspaces indeed can very well solve this: you then press Ctrl+Shift+Right or Left to switch from one view (desktop with terminals) to another (desktop with file manager/browser)

Comment: yes, after using it for few times. I felt workspaces is really convinient to organise stuff.